# External DVD player not showing up in Finder

Tags: virtualbox, dvd

I have a MacBook Air running Ventura. If I plug in an external DVD player, the DVD player light blinks but the DVD doesn't show up in Finder. The DVD and player work on my other MacBook running Ventura. My suspicion is that something broke when I installed Oracle VirtualBox (I uninstalled it).

Other USB devices work on the same port. I have a DVD in the drive. The drive is using a combo cable.

Comment: Do other USB devices work properly in the same port?  Do you have a DVD in the drive?

Comment: Is the DVD drive equipped with USBA, USBC or a combo cable?